# Error for every other command

Tags: error-handling

```
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

I keep getting this error for `sudo apt-get install` and `sudo apt-get clean`.

Comment: That's only a **N**otice, not an **E**rror. Are you having an actual issue updating or installing software?

Comment: Yep! 
I have lots of trouble updating

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the specifics

Comment: Like ? What do you want me to include?I did tell on what commands I get the error

Comment: You have been told that what you have provided is not an error (that said, if you want to get rid of it, just delete the offending file). Do you have any actual problem like a package not installing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error. To resolve this issue, simply open up a terminal window and enter the following command:

`rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-old`

Comment: I tried that but it isn't working

Comment: What does it say when you try that?

Try this:

`cd /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` then this:
`sudo rm  20auto-upgrades.ucf-old`

Comment: rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-old': No such file or directory

Comment: that's the error I get

Comment: Run the command `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` in terminal and show me the output.